# Check DB updated within Selenium

Tags: database, selenium

Do you possibly have any hints on how I could make some basic DB checks from inside Selenium? 
I have been playing with getEval and runScript etc but I'm not fluent in "Selenium-ish' so I have no idea how to go through with this.

Anyone done this?

Comment: Why would you want to make DB checks using Selenium? Selenium is for front end tests.

Comment: What I am looking for is a way to verify that the contents of a very large and rather complex form as it is committed is stored correctly in the database and the test should be automated as far as possible. I have been looking at tools for verifying databases and it would be nice if there was a way of automating these tests.

Comment: yeah i would think this would work too.

Answer (score 2):

Selenium is "just a library for clicking buttons in the browser".
You need to write a class/function in the language of your choice, which will:

1. use selenium library to open browser, fill in and submit the form,
2. use some database library to connect and get the values from db,
3. compare received data with the expected ones.

The library name from `2` depends on the language and the database you use.